# Change Group by Order

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

Consider this table:

```
id | machine | manual| etc.
1     1          0
2     2          0
3     1          1
```

I want to retrieve the records grouped by Machine. I know that the manual records are always inserted after the automatic ones.
In MySQL I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY machine DESC
```

And the records retrieved are:

```
id | machine | manual| etc.
2     2          0
3     1          1
```

Because the GROUP BY of MySQL works in ASC and the first record it finds is the one it considers. So by placing the DESC in the GROUP BY it works in reverse and since I know that the manuals always come after this would work for my solution. But how can I do this in Doctrine?

```
$qb = Query Builder 'b'
$qb->groupBy('b.machine DESC');
```

Does anyone know how to do this without sub querys?
Thank you

Comment: try using `orderBy('b.machine', 'DESC');`

Comment: @NishantNair the Order By applies after the group by is done so it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with `group by` is against the sql standard, and may not work if only full group by sql mode is configured in MySQL. This is the default setting of the recent versions of MySQL.

Since you want the latest record identified by an auto increment id, you can achieve the expected outcome with a self `left join`:

```
select t1.*
from table t1
left join table t2 on t1.machine=t2.machine and t1.id<t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

Basically, with the `t1.id<t2.id` join condition you get all records where t2.id is greater for the same machine. If a greater t2.id is not found, a `null` value is returned - indicating that this is the latest record for the given machine. This is the record we keep with the `where t2.id is null` clause.

Comment: I already have a solution if what I requested can't be done. Thanks :)